# Docker/Ansible: ERROR! The playbook could not be found

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm quite new to software development and having some issues setting up a docker container.

I've pull the docker container and run it. Now I want to apply some configuration to my container with

```
docker run --rm --network="ansible_default" -v C:\folder\folder1\ansible\playbooks:/ansible/playbooks docker.<address>/ansible ansible-playbook -i host localhost.playbook.yml
```

But when I run the above code, it just gives an error:

`ERROR the playbook localhost.playbook.yml does not appear to be a file`

I am running on administration powershell and have cd into the folder that contains the yaml files. (so inside `C:\folder\folder1\ansible\playbooks`)

Do I need ansible installed? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The docker container exits with a code 2, I'm supposed to be able to access it via `localhost:8080` but it's just a blank screen. `Exited(2)` I'm not too sure what it means, haven't found much success online.

Comment: Add the option `--workdir /ansible/playbooks` to your docker command (in the docker options before your image name, for example before your other `-v ...` option), and see if it works. If it does not, I strongly suggest you read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section and then [edit] your question. As is you'll probably only get tips based on wild guesses (as the one in this comment...)

Comment: Wasn't able to get it working :(  Okay I'll try add more details into the question - thanks for your help though

Comment: `I'm supposed to be able to access it via localhost:8080` <= with a command launching an ansible playbook (i.e. `ansible-playbook -i host localhost.playbook.yml` on your docker command line), and without even binding the port locally, there is absolutely no way this can ever happen. You seem to not be really clear about what you are actually doing. Since we  are not either and cannot guess for you, answering this question is just impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to reinstall Docker.